# Php for each how to remove characters

Tags: php, json

I tested this on firefox and it works fine, but in IE it doesn't work because of comma on last part of array. Now how can I remove comma using php?

Actual result:

```
{image : 'folder/pic1.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic1.jpg', url : ''},
{image : 'folder/pic2.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic2.jpg', url : ''},
{image : 'folder/pic3.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic3.jpg', url : ''},
```

Expected result:

```
{image : 'folder/pic1.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic1.jpg', url : ''},
{image : 'folder/pic2.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic2.jpg', url : ''},
{image : 'folder/pic3.jpg', title : '', thumb : 'folder/pic3.jpg', url : ''}
```

Code:

```
<?php 
$directory = "pic/";

$images = glob("".$directory."{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.PNG,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);

if ($images != false)
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({
            slideshow:   1,//Slideshow on/off
            autoplay:    1,//Slideshow starts playing automatically
            start_slide: 1,//Start slide (0 is random)
            stop_loop:   0,
            slides:      [// Slideshow Images

            <?php
    foreach( $images as $key => $value){
                 echo "{image : '$value', title : '', thumb : '$value', url : ''},";
            }
            ?>
            ],
            progress_bar: 1,// Timer for each slide
            mouse_scrub: 0
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: that last comma is becoming a "nightmare", use a counter and increment each loop, if counter value is equal to the count($images) then skip printing the comma ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to hand-code your own JSON. Use `json_encode()`

```
echo json_encode($images);
```

To answer the question nonetheless, there's two ways of avoiding the trailing comma (which should indeed be removed, even if Firefox et al let you get away with it)

1 - conditionlise its output in your loop

```
$arr = array('apple', 'pear', 'orange');
foreach($arr as $key => $fruit) {
    echo $fruit;
    if ($key < count($arr) - 1) echo ', ';
}
```

Note this will work only for indexed arrays. For associative ones, you'd have to set up your own counter variable (since `$key` would not be a number).

2 - remove it afterwards, e.g. with REGEX

```
$str = "apple, pear, orange, ";
$str = preg_replace('/, ?$/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Upvoted Utkanos' answer to use `json_encode` but to get your code to work you can use `end` to compare if your values are the same, or `key` to verify the keys.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
  if ($value == end($array)) {
      // Last element by value
  }

  end($array);
  if ($key == key($array)) {
      // Last element by key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own JSON, use `json_encode`:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'slideshow' => 1,
    ...
);

foreach ($images ...) {
    $data['slides'][] = array('image' => ...);
}

?>

$.supersized(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```